# How to bind MacAddress for docker service in swarm mode

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have a Docker swarm environment includes three nodes

```
manager node: bd0
worker node 1: bd1
worker node 2: bd1
```

In my case, I used the following commands to create the cluster, network and service

```
# init swarm
sudo docker swarm init

# add worker nodes
sudo docker swarm join \
  --token SWMTKN-1-0x11m2uk7ps9bh7nflkxwirgv0syvacl18rut3hilz4i9lgis3-d9m22hixt0b57hjj81im8bqdl \
  192.168.0.109:2377

# create overlay network
sudo docker network create --driver overlay myswarm

# create the service
sudo docker service create --replicas 3 --name mynginx -p 8000:80 --network=myswarm nginx
```

Now, the service is working well.

But now I have requirement, I want to bind the fixed the MacAddress (not ip) for each container in this service. Because we have some program need bind the mac address. How can I do in swarm mode?

In normal mode, we can use the following command to do it. But how to do the similar thing in swarm mode?

```
sudo docker run -it --rm --net mynet --mac-address 88:88:88:88:88:88 busybox
```

Many thanks.